# Android: finishAndRemoveTask() doesn't close the app

Tags: java, android, exit

So this is what I tried to close my app:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

public class PlayMSActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ImageButton exit = findViewById(R.id.msexit);
        ImageButton start = findViewById(R.id.msstart);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    finishAndRemoveTask();
                } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    finishAffinity();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(PlayMSActivity.this, AnotherClass.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Code from AnotherClass:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AnotherClass extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ImageButton ret = findViewById(R.id.ret1);
        ret.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            startActivity(new Intent(AnotherClass.this, PlayMSActivity.class));
            finish();
        });
    }
}
```

The resulting behavior: The app shortly blinks away, but then reappears after few milliseconds.
Sometimes, it closes as intended, but only every ~7th attempt. The device I'm testing on is a Tab A with the newest API installed. The same applies for tests on an emulated Tab with SDK version Q.

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: Any chance that there are other activities which are opened in the background? which flags do you use when you move between activities in your app?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This brought some more clarity about where the problem happens.
If I start the app, I have a SplashScreenActivity that directly launches this PlayMSActivity and calls finish() on itself. Calling finishAndRemoveTask() directly afterwards works as intended. 
The problem is after I enter another activity and then go back to this one. I'll just check it and leave an update in a few seconds :)

Comment: Thank you very much @ymz - this exactly was my problem, I updated the post to include the erroneous code and posted an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what my problem was.
I started new Activities, but didn't finish this one. I simply had to add a `finish();` after each time I started a new Activity at the `start.setOnClickListener` part, like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(PlayMSActivity.this, AnotherClass.class));
finish();
```

There are other solutions as well, but this shows where my problem was: I started this activity from other Activities, but didn't finish it in the first place. So there were several unfinished Activity instances of this class, which resulted in having to close them one by one.

Tip for others: Don't start an activity that you are already running, or finish it if you know you will restart it anyway.